# How to compare a list in a text file to a list in a directory and print the difference?

Tags: python, list

Right now it's returning the whole list of files from the directory rather than the difference between the directory and the text file. Any ideas?

```
import os, sys
path = "C:\\Users\\INstokes\\Desktop\\CityPts\\"

old_files = "C:\\Users\\INstokes\\Desktop\\CityPts\\file.txt"
new_files = os.listdir( path )


text_file = open(old_files, "r")
old_list = text_file.readlines()


s = set(old_list)
temp3 = [x.strip() for x in new_files if x.strip() not in old_list]
print temp3

text_file.close()
```

Comment: How are the file names in ```old_files``` formatted? Do they included the whole file path or only the name?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you use [`text_file.readlines()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm), you get back a list of the lines including line endings.

So you get something like this back:

```
>>> old_list
['This is 1st line\n', 'This is 2nd line\n', 
 'This is 3rd line\n', 'This is 4th line\n', 
 'This is 5th line\n']
```

Then in this line:

```
temp3 = [x.strip() for x in new_files if x.strip() not in old_list]
```

you are comparing each filepath in `new_files`, stripped, to those in the `old_list` which all have newlines at the end, so of course they will never match (You also never use the set `s` that is created, though that is more just a performance concern).

You actually want to be stripping from `old_list`, not `new_files`:

```
old_list = text_file.readlines()
s = set(item.rstrip() for item in old_list)
temp3 = [x for x in new_files if x not in s]
```

Putting it all together and condensing a bit:

```
import os
import os    

def diff_dir_with_filelist(directory, filepath):
    new_files =  os.listdir(directory)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as text_file:
        old_list = text_file.readlines()

    old_files = set(item.rstrip() for item in old_list)
    return [x for x in new_files if x not in old_files]

results = diff_dir_with_filelist("C:\\Users\\INstokes\\Desktop\\CityPts\\", "C:\\Users\\INstokes\\Desktop\\CityPts\\file.txt")
print(results)
```

Comment: I tried running this script with the os.listdir(path) specified and although it returns no errors, it also fails to print anything when it should be printing the difference. Any ideas?

Comment: the function takes as input the desired directory and the filepath to diff its contents against and returns a list of those that are in the directory but not the list of files in the given file.  If you want to see them you'll have to print out the returned result. Will update

Comment: also, just caught a `NameError` with the code which was probably causing unexpected behavior.  Can you try again?

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm new to python so thank you for assisting me. It works when I print the results.

Comment: Great glad to hear it Anthony. Also, if my answer was helpful for you if you could please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it that would be much appreciated.